# Coupling Widget Variables - input --> feed webscraper

Tags: variables, web, tkinter, web-scraping, widget

I'm running into an error for "TypeError: must be str, not Entry" with my program.
I first tried casting with Str().
I tried using StringVar.

I've read some of the posts on here and in the Python documentation about coupling widget variables, and that because I'm in Tkinter --> i need to use sub-variable of Variable.
After followign the Python documentation, I introduced 'contents' variable as a StringVar.

I want to pick up the user inputted string, and add that to another string inside another variable. I want to then use that as the URL for my webscraper to crawl over.

N.B. The webscraper code works well.
The gui (while not pretty) also does the functions.

The problem seems to be on the conveying user input as a string. Any folks with any ideas?

```
    import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib.request 

import tkinter as tk
import os


#here is the application variable
contents = StringVar()
        # set it to some value
contents.set("this is a variable")
        # tell the entry widget to watch this variable
user_entry["textvariable"] = contents


#search and button functions
def myclick():
    label = tk.Label(lower_frame, text='Searching...')
    label.place(relheight = 0.1, relwidth = 1)

def search_items(product):
    scrape_URL = ('https://www.wickes.co.uk/search?text='+ contents.get())
    page_html = requests.get(scrape_URL)
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    names = [x.text.strip() for x in page_soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'product-card__title     product-card__title-v2'})]
    prices = [x.text.strip() for x in page_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-card__price-value'})]

    wickes_product_dict = dict(zip(names, prices))

    print(("\n".join("{}\t{}".format(k, v) for k, v in wickes_product_dict.items())).json())

    #label for the output  on the GUI
    #label_products = tk.Label(lower_frame, textvariable= names)
    #label_products.place(relheight = 0.9, relwidth = 1)

#======== GUI ======= #

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH, bg="blue")
canvas.pack()

#use to organise the widgets 
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#80c1ff")
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.1, anchor = 'n'  )

# This is entry widget
user_entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg='#39BDFB', textvariable=contents)
user_entry.place(relwidth = 0.65, relheight = 1)
user_entry.insert(0, "Enter Product: ")


search_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Search Items", font="Arial 10")
search_button.place(relx = 0.7, rely = 0, relheight = 1, relwidth=0.3)
search_button["command"] = lambda: search_items(contents)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the `Entry` widget? The method to get data out of the widget is well documented.

Comment: Will refocus there. Thanks Bryan